# How to make Spark SQL the default interpreter in a Zeppelin Notebook?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

At office, we use Zeppelin Notebooks with Spark as the default interpreter. Most of the time I use Spark SQL. Here is a simple example:

```
%SQL
select * from db.table1
```

How to make Spark SQL the default interpreter such that I do not have to write `%SQL` in each cell?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create New Note
2. Select Default Interpreter
3. sql

[image]